# Analog Sound Sensor V2 giving aleator numbers

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I`m using an Analog Sound Sensor V2 with an Arduino UNO. I`m doing a simple thing for know, I just want to read the values from the sensor. So, I have only Arduino and Sensor coneccted ( in this way: red wire for VCC, black for Ground, Blue for Analog Input, at A0 on Arduino Board).
The code is that:

```
    void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}
void loop()
{
    int val;
    val=analogRead(A0);  
    Serial.println(val);    
    delay(100);
}
```

And I`m reciving on Serial a lot of values , that for me seems to be random like:

> 0 
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   450
>   340
>   1023
>   1023
>   870
>   and so

Comment: If anyone knows why is happening this? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the sensor? How I can test if it`s work good?